# Is it possible to call Go functions in one transactions?

Tags: t-sql, go, transactions

I store a double linked list in PostgreSQL. I have a Go API to manage this list.

There is a function that creates new `Node` (in specific position). Let's assume there is an INSERT SQL query inside of it.

Also, there is a function that deletes `Node` (by id). Let's assume there is a DELETE SQL query inside of it.

It is well known that if you need to move a `Node` to different position you should call DeleteNode() function and CreateNode() function. So there is the third function called MoveNode()

```
func MoveNode() error {
  if err := DeleteNode(); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  if err := CreateNode(); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return nil
}
```

But these functions (which are inside of MoveNode() should be called in one transaction.

**Is there a way to "merge" functions in Go? Or what is the way to solve this problem (except copy & paste code from 2 functions to the third)?**

p.s The idea is simple: you have two functions which do some SQL queries and you need to do these queries in one transaction (or call 2 functions in one transaction)

Comment: Can you share DeleteNode() and CreateNode() code here ? 

Isnt there tx.Commit() which you can use after executing create and delete query ?

Comment: @It is possible to use tx.Commit() inside single function like DeleteNode() or CreateNode(). But I can't find the way to wrap this functions and then call tx.Commit. Also I don't think it will be useful to provide code for DeleteNode() and CreateNode() functions as there are just several standard SQL queries inside of them.

Comment: Just change your code so that `DeleteNode` and `CreateNode` aren't assuming they're executing a transaction each. Without seeing any of the relevant code it's hard to say more.

Comment: @Adrian Right now `DeleteNode` and `CreateNode` both run transactions. For example `CreateNode` does SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE queries.

Comment: Right, that's the problem. See my previous comment.

Comment: @Adrian Ok, but what should they return in this case (instead of error after transaction)?

Comment: Again, without seeing any of the relevant code it's hard to say more.

Comment: All the functions, be it, DeleteNode() and CreateNode() will need to be passed the transaction which you get when you do tx := db.Begin() and they can return the response from tx.Exec(query) and then function calling DeleteNode and CreateNode have to do tx.Commit()  and I guess this will solve your problem.

So you move the transaction out of those functions and just have tx.Exec(query) inside DeleteNode and CreateNode functions.

Please let me know if this helps ?

Comment: Your code will look like : func DeleteNode(transactionFromDbBegin) (responseFromExec, errorFromExec) and func CreateNode(transactionFromDbBegin) (responseFromExec, errorFromExec) and MoveNode will have tx = DB.Begin() and call DeleteNode(tx) and call CreateNode(tx) and end with tx.Commit(). I think this should do the trick.

Comment: @Kartavya Yes, that is what I was looking for, thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to go about this here will be to move tx.Commit() outside the query execution functions (DeleteNode() and CreateNode() here)

Suggested Solution :

```
func MoveNode() error {
   tx, err := db.Begin()
   // err handling

  res, err := DeleteNode(tx)
  // err handling

  res, err := CreateNode(tx)
  // err handling

  tx.Commit()
}

func DeleteNode(transactionFromDbBegin) (responseFromExec, errorFromExec) {
    //...
}

func CreateNode(transactionFromDbBegin) (responseFromExec, errorFromExec) {
    //...
}
```

This should do the trick.